# Advagg Cache-Control > 1 year

Tags: .htaccess, css-js-aggregation

I am trying to use Advagg module. All's ok, but unshit.com states that all its css and js files Cache-Control is set more that a year.

In .htaccess

```
# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
# Turn on Expires and set default to 0
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

# Set up caching on media files for 1 year (forever?)
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
    ExpiresDefault A29030400
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

# Set up caching on media files for 1 week
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf)$">
    ExpiresDefault A2419200
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

# Set up 2 Hour caching on commonly updated files
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html|js|css)$">
    ExpiresDefault A7200
    Header append Cache-Control "private"
</FilesMatch>

# Force no caching for dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl|htm)$">
    ExpiresActive Off
    Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

mod_expires and mod_headers are enabled.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.21 Thanks for pointing this out.
Answer will be in here eventually - https://drupal.org/node/2161115